# Concat wasn't working in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, null, concatenation

My table:

```
table1

first   last     full
Joe     Smith    NULL
John    Doe      NULL
```

My query:

```
update table1
set full = concat(first, " ", last)
```

It didn't do anything - immediately said 0 rows affected, taking 33.2 ms. Then I changed the default value for the column from NULL to nothing and poof, without even running the query again, the full names appeared in the column. Problem solved. But can anybody tell be why? I am lost.

Answer (score 0):

> [CONCAT() returns NULL if any argument is NULL.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Comment: mmm, perhaps this isn't relevant. The column was populated **without re-running the update**?

Comment: correct, I'm thinking it could be something with my program (Sequel Pro) having quirky settings but I'm not sure.

Comment: sure sounds quirky, sorry nothing more to offer